# How to store password in variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

I have a function that generates a new password everytime I run the program. I want to know if its possible to store the generated password in a variable or function. How can i do this?
code is below:

```
def generateOTP():
    # Declare a string variable
    # which stores all string
    string = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    OTP = ""
    length = len(string)
    for i in range(8):
        OTP += string[math.floor(random.random() * length)]

    return OTP

print(generateOTP())
```

I'm not sure how to go around this. Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: `password = generateOTP()`?

Comment: nope. Tried that. That just generates another password. Needs to stay the same.

Comment: If you want to get back the password next time you start your program you should save it to a file. See [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the tutorial. (Disclaimer: no sane application stores the actual password, only a hash value)

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. bro it's already in you OTP var

```py
import math, random
def generateOTP():
    # Declare a string variable
    # which stores all string
    string = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    OTP = ""
    length = len(string)
    for i in range(8):
        OTP += string[math.floor(random.random() * length)]

    return OTP


otp = generateOTP()

print("here you go: ",otp)
```

2. If you want to store it permanently it can only happen if you generate txt file and then save it

```py
def generateOTP():
    # Declare a string variable
    # which stores all string
    string = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    OTP = ""
    length = len(string)
    for i in range(8):
        OTP += string[math.floor(random.random() * length)]

    return OTP


otp = generateOTP()

with open('otp.txt', 'w') as O:
    O.write(otp)
```